# How can I convert a specific string date to date or datetime in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, casting, databricks, date-format

I have this string pattern in my Spark dataframe: 'Sep 14, 2014, 1:34:36 PM'.

I want to convert this to date or datetime format, using Databricks and Spark.

I've already tried the cast and to_date functions, but nothing works and I got null return everytime.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to_date() with a format using the [datetime patterns](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) matching your needs? Yours look like `"E d, yyyy, KK:mm:ss a"`

Comment: Some typos: E should be MMM (E can't be used for parsing), and as your hour can have a single digit, only one "h" is needed. Also put one or two "d" depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a created table like this:

```scala
var ds = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  "Sep 14, 2014, 01:34:36 PM"
)).toDF("date")
```

Through the following statement:

```scala
ds = ds.withColumn("casted", to_timestamp(col("date"), "MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss aa"))
```

You get this result:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|date                     |casted             |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|Sep 14, 2014, 01:34:36 PM|2014-09-14 13:34:36|
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

which should be useful to you. You can use `to_date` or other APIs that require a datetime format, good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vilalabinot! It worked for me, but just when I put only one 'a' in the pattern, otherwise I get the error "Too many pattern letters: a". I also had to put only one 'h' for hours, because my hours have only one character, otherwise I get the error "could not be parsed at index 14".  In the end, the pattern was: 'MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a'. Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: Guys, how about this PT-BR format: '8 de jan de 2014 08:57:15'? How can I convert this? I tried the pattern ''d m yyyy hh:mm:ss'', without sucess.

Comment: You can first `regexp_replace(col("date"), "de ", "")` then `to_timestamp(col("date"), "d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

Your date/time stamp string is incorrect.  You have 1 instead of 01.

```
#
# 1 - Create sample dataframe + view
#

# required library
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
  ("1", "Sep 14, 2014, 01:34:36 pm")
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["row_id", "date_string1"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# expand date range into list of dates
df1 = df1.withColumn("time_stamp1", to_timestamp(col("date_string1"), "MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a")) 
  
# show schema
df1.printSchema()

# show data
display(df1)
```

This code produces the correct answer.

[image]

If the data has 1:34:36, it fails.  You can use a when clause to pick the correct conversion.

Comment: why not match only one h?

Comment: I just retested with "h" in Azure Databricks.  Works like a charm.